# Android keyboard with fewer than 26 keys for English text entry

Tags: android, user-interface, keyboard, virtual-keyboard, keyboard-layout

Recently, I came across an innovative Android keyboard that used well-under 26 letters to allow you to enter English text.

It didn't employ the old T9 data input method, or anything archaic like that.  It was based on a completely new methodology for consumer virtual keyboards.

If I remember correctly, it had about 8-10 primary buttons, perhaps arranged in a hexagonal arrangement.  The reviews were mixed, given that most people probably weren't willing to try something new long enough to become efficient at it.

The article I read talked about the developer trying all sorts of different key arrangements before landing on the one they chose to implement.

I've searched extensively for it, and I haven't been able to find it (again) yet.  I think it was available from the Google Play Store, but I'm not 100% certain.

Please recommend an Android virtual keyboard that allows you to enter English text via less than 26 primary keys, and does not rely on archaic data-input methods like T9.

Any price is fine.  Availability on Google Play Store not required.

Comment: Is there a screenshot of this keyboard?

Comment: @Gevrol I searched all my notes, and I cannot find a reference to the particular app I saw; thus, I'm going by memory.  I did find Keybee Keyboard (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.keybeeproject.keybee), which doesn't match my description above, but does look interesting.